# Proving total boundedness of a subset of a metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, proof-writing

This preface of this question is related to [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373148/proving-completeness-of-a-metric-space) question I posted, but what I am proving is quite different. So I am starting a new question.

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the infinite Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself. Define the metric $d(x,y) = \sum_{t \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}} \beta^{-t} \rho(x_t, y_t)$ where $\rho(x_t, y_t) = \min\{|x_t - y_t|, 1\}$ for some fixed $\beta>1$ and for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ where $x = (x_0, x_1, \cdots)$ and $y=(y_0, y_1, \cdots)$. Prove that $[0,1]^{\infty}$ is a totally bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ under $d$.

The definition of total boundness that I'm working with is:

A set $A$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ is totally bounded if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in A$ such that $A \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{n} B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$.

How can I use the above definition to prove that $[0,1]^{\infty}$ is totally bounded? So what I need to do is find $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \in [0,1]^{\infty}$ where $x_1 = (x_{1, 0}, x_{1, 1}, \cdots)$, $x_2 = (x_{2, 0}, x_{2, 1}, \cdots)$, so that the finite union of the open balls around these elements contains $[0,1]^{\infty}$. But I have no idea how to find these particular $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ to complete the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the infinite Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself"

How big is the $\infty$? Countable? Uncountable?

Comment: The question didn't specify, it just means $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$. That is, if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, then $x$ is of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots)$ where $x_t \in \mathbb{R}$ for $t = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$.

Comment: In that case I guess it's countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's gather up a couple of things that are useful:

1. For $x,y\in[0,1]^\infty$, we know that $\rho(x_t,y_t)\leq 1$.
2. $$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^{-t}\rho(x_t,y_t)\leq \sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^{-t} = \frac{1}{1-\beta}=:B$$
3. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $T$ such that $$\sum_{t=T}^\infty \beta^{-t} < \epsilon$$

---

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$, let $T$ be such that $$\sum_{t=T}^\infty \beta^{-t} < \frac\epsilon2$$ and take $x^1=(0,0,0\dots)$.

Now, take any $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ such that for $i<T$, you have $|x_i|<\frac\epsilon{2B}$. Then,

$$d(x,x_1)=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^{-t} \rho(x^1_t, x_t) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^{-t}|x_i|\\=\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}\beta^{-t}|x_t| + \sum_{i=T}^\infty \beta^{-t}|x_t|$$

Now, for the first sum, use $|x_t|<\frac\epsilon{2B}$, and for the second, use the fact that $|x_t|\leq 1$ to get

$$d(x,x_1)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2B}\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}\beta^{-t} + \sum_{t=T}^\infty \beta^{-t}\\
\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2B}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \beta^{-t} +\sum_{t=T}^\infty \beta^{-t}\\
\leq \frac\epsilon{2B}\cdot B + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

So, we have shown that $x_1\in B(x^1,\epsilon)$

---

The take-away:

$x$ is only bounded on the **first** $T$ coordinates, and it can be anything for the other coordinates. Therefore, in a way, you only need to split $\mathbb R^T$ in a sort of chessboard-style pattern to get the full coverage. For example, you would take $x^2=(\frac{\epsilon}{2B}, 0,0,0\dots)$, and in general (taking $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2B}$) you would take $x_n$ to form the set

$$\left\{\left(k_1\delta, k_2\delta,k_3\delta,\dots, k_T\delta, 0,0,0\dots\right)|k_1,k_2\dots, k_T\in\left\{0,1,2,\dots\left\lceil\frac{1}{\delta}\right\rceil\right\}\right\}$$

which is clearly finite. The proof that this is a good selection is similar to the proof of how $x^1$ covers the set

$$\{(x_1,x_2\dots| x_1\leq\delta, x_2\leq\delta,\dots, x_T\leq\delta\}$$